# Are the number of solutions to $ax^2+bxy+cy^2\equiv u\pmod{p}$, $(x,y)\in\{0,\dotsc,p-1\}$, the same for all units $u$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $F={\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z}$.   With $a,b,c\in F$, let $Q(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ where $p\nmid b^2-4ac$.    I wish to prove that the number of solutions $(x,y)\in F^2$ of
$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=u$$ is the same for all units $u\in F$.

For example, when $p=5$, the equation $x^2-2xy+3y^2=u$ has one solution when $u=0$ and 6 solutions for each of $u=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398200/the-number-of-solutions-of-ax2by2-equiv-1-pmodp-is-p-left-frac-abp

Comment: Clearly, this isn't true. Consider x^2+y^2 =0. If -1 is not a square in F then this has one solution (0,0). If -1 is a square it has at least order |F| solutions of the form (a,ia), with i^2=-1. The number of solutions is well understood but depends on more than just if u is a unit. There is a rich classical theory to binary quadratic forms in finite fields.

Comment: @MarkLewko  the intended question is "why the same for all units in $F$", not that the count should be independent of $F$. That is consistent with your comment (as $F$ varies).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $F$ be a finite field, such as $\mathbf Z/(p)$ but it could be a more general finite field (including of characteristic $2$, and not necessarily $\mathbf Z/(2)$, so I won't make a change of linear variables using division by $2$ as in another answer).  If both $a = 0$ and $c = 0$ then the equation becomes $bxy = u$, so necessarily $b \not= 0$ since $b^2 - 4ac = b^2$ and you said $b^2 - 4ac \not= 0$. A solution $(x,y)$ has both coordinates not equal to $0$, with $y = u/(bx)$.  Thus
the solution set for each $u \in F^\times$ is $\{(x,u/(bx)) : x \in F^\times\}$, whose size is $|F| - 1$.

If $a \not= 0$ or $c \not= 0$ then by symmetry (swapping the roles of $x$ and $y$ in the equation) we can suppose $a \not= 0$.  Then
solving $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 = u$ is the same as solving $x^2 + (b/a)xy + (c/a)y^2 = u/a$, and as $u$ runs over $F^\times$ so does $u/a$. Thus we can suppose $a = 1$: we want to count solutions of $x^2 + bxy + cy^2 = u$ in $F^2$. Set $R = F[t]/(t^2 + bt + c)$, a finite ring.  The norm map ${\rm N}_{R/F} \colon R \to F$ is multiplicative, and using the basis $\{1,t\}$ we can realize your expression for $Q(x,y)$ as a norm value: for $x, y \in F$,
$$
{\rm N}_{R/F}(x + yt) = 
\det\begin{pmatrix}x&-cy\\y&x-by\end{pmatrix} = x^2 - bxy + cy^2 = (-x)^2 + b(-x)y + cy^2.
$$
Therefore the equation $x^2 + bxy + cy^2 = u$ is the same as ${\rm N}_{R/F}(-x+yt) = u$ for $x, y \in F$. On units the norm map ${\rm N}_{R/F} \colon R^\times \to F^\times$ is a group homomorphism, so as with all homomorphisms between finite groups, all values are taken on an equal number of times.
Thus it remains to show the norm map ${\rm N}_{R/F} \colon R^\times \to F^\times$  is surjective.

Case 1: $t^2 + bt + c$ is irreducible in $F[t]$. Then $R$ is a field, so $R^\times$ is cyclic and the norm map $R^\times \to F^\times$ on the nonzero elements of finite fields is onto (if $|F| = q$ then $|R| = q^2$ and a generator of $R^\times$ is mapped to a generator of $F^\times$).

Case 2: $t^2 + bt + c$ is reducible in $F[t]$. Write it as $(t-r)(t-s)$.
Since $b^2 - 4c = (r-s)^2$, from $b^2 - 4c \not= 0$ we have
$r \not= s$. Then $R \cong F[t]/(t-r) \times F[t]/(t-s) \cong F \times F$, and in the basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, the norm mapping
has the formula ${\rm N}_{R/F}(x,y) = xy$, which maps $R^\times = F^\times \times F^\times$ onto $F^\times$.

You definitely want $b^2 - 4ac \not= 0$, since if $b^2 - 4ac = 0$ your desired conclusion can fail. As a simple example, consider $Q(x,y) = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = (x+y)^2$. Then the equation $Q(x,y) = u$ has solutions in $F$ if $u$ is a nonzero square in $F$ and it has no solutions in $F$ if $u$ is a nonzero nonsquare in $F$. When
$F = \mathbf Z/(p)$ for odd $p$ (or more generally $F$ is a finite field of odd characteristic), half of $F^\times$ is squares and half is nonsquares, so the equation $(x+y)^2 = u$ for $u \in F^\times$ has solutions for half the values of $u$.

Comment: Perhaps $Q(x, y) = x^2$ is even simpler than $Q(x, y) = x^2 + 2x y + y^2$. 

Comment: @LSpice  that option had occurred to me, but I wanted to use an example where all three terms are present. Admittedly it's only a linear change of variables away from the example you pointed out.

Comment: I have a followup question  - #425072 - that might be of interest.

Answer (score 8):

The following works for any finite field $F$. Consider the projective curve
$$ C : ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 = uz^2. $$
Your conditions $b^2-4ac\in F^*$ and $u\in F^*$ imply that $C$ is non-singular, since it has degree $2$, the genus of $C$ is $0$, and elementary (or non-elementary) methods show that $C(F)\ne\emptyset$, so $C\cong\mathbb P^1_F$, where the isomorphism is defined over $F$. Hence
$$ \#C(F) = \#\mathbb P^1(F) = |F|+1. $$
So the question becomes whether the point(s) at infinity, i.e., the points with $z=0$, are in $C(F)$. This is clearly independent of $u$, and it depends on whether $b^2-4ac$ is a square in $F$. Hence
$$ \#\bigl\{ (x,y)\in F : ax^2+bxy+cy^2=u\bigr\}
= |F| -  \left(\frac{b^2-4ac}{F}\right),
$$
where
$$
\left(\frac{A}{F}\right)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $A\in{F^*}^2$,}\\
-1&\text{if $A\notin{F^*}^2$.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I have a followup question  - #425072 - that might be of interest.

Comment: @user47804 First, if you're going to refer people to another MO question, include it as a link. Second, Keith Conrad explained in his comment to your other question that proving that $N(p^n)=p^{n-1}N(p)$ can be done using Hensel's lemma, since in your case the your algebraic variety is smooth (i.e.,  non-singular) mod $p$.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by @JoeSilverman's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424872), I've updated this answer to handle any odd-characteristic field $F$, and to remove a few ugly case distinctions from the original argument; but I do assume that the characteristic is not $2$, as @KConrad [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/a/424877).

Put $\theta = \dfrac{b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4a c}}2$, where we have chosen a square root of $b^2 - 4a c$ that does not equal $-b$ (either one, if $4a c \ne 0$).

We have that $a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 = a x^2 + (\theta + a c\theta^{-1})x y + c y^2$ equals $(a x + \theta y)(x + c\theta^{-1}y)$.  If $\theta$ belongs to $F$, then the change of variables $\begin{pmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & \theta \\ 1 & c\theta^{-1} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ is non-singular (with determinant $a c\theta^{-1} - \theta = (a c - \theta^2)\theta^{-1} = \sqrt{b^2 - 4a c}$), so we are considering solutions $(x', y')$ of $x'y' = u$, which form an $F^\times$-torsor.  (In particular, if $F$ is finite, then there are $\lvert F^\times\rvert$ of them.)

If, on the other hand, $\theta$ does not belong to $F$, then $b^2 - 4a c$ is not a square in $F$, so $a$ is non-$0$.  Then $a x^2 + bx y + cy^2$ equals $a^{-1}(a x + \theta y)(a x + a c\theta^{-1} y) = a^{-1}N_{F[\theta]/F}(a x + \theta y)$, so parameterising solutions of $a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 = u$ is the same as parameterising solutions of $N_{F[\theta]/F}(a x + \theta y) = u a$.  Since $(x, y) \mapsto a x + \theta y$ is an isomorphism of $F$-vector spaces (*not* of $F$-algebras) $F \oplus F \to F[\theta]$, we are parameterising the fibre of the norm map over $u a$.  In general, of course, fibres are either empty or torsors for $\ker N_{F[\theta]/F}$; and, if $F$ if finite, so that the norm map is surjective, then all fibres are torsors, hence have size $\lvert F[\theta]^\times\rvert/\lvert F^\times\rvert$.

Comment: The concept of "torsor" is new to me (is there a simple definition for fields of prime order?).    I followed your first answer pretty well though.

Comment: @user47804, torsors are to spaces with a group action as affine spaces are to sets with a vector-space action.  That is, you may think of a torsor as "a group where you've forgotten the identity element", just as you may think of an affine space as "a vector space where you've forgotten the origin". In this concrete example, once you pick one solution $(x'_0, y'_0)$ of $x'y' = u$, every other solution is of the form $(x'_0 t, t^{-1}y'_0)$ for a unique $t \in F^\times$, but there is no "best" solution; so the space of solutions is like $F^\times$, but forgetting which element is "the identity".

Comment: I have a followup question  - #425072 - that might be of interest.

Comment: @user47804, as @‍KConrad says [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425072/the-number-of-solutions-to-ax2bxycy2-equiv-k-pmodpn-x-y-in-0-do#comment1092665_425072), what you are looking for is Hensel's lemma.